# How to get chunks of 15 minutes for the given time duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to get chunks of 15 minutes for a given time duration.

eg. `@start_time = '10:00 am'`   `@end_time = '1:00 pm'`
Then it should return a table like this:

```
10:00 AM 
10:15 AM
10:30 AM
10:45 AM
11:00 AM
11:15 AM
11:30 AM
11:45 AM
...and so on till
12:45 PM
```

I have searched a lot on google but did not found anything helpful. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a system table to make the rows and `DATEADD` to calc your periods:

```
declare @start_time time = '10:00:00 AM', @end_time time = '01:00:00 PM';

select convert(time, dateadd(MINUTE, (n-1)*15, convert(datetime, @start_time))) x, *
from (select top (DATEDIFF(hh, @start_time, @end_time)*4) ROW_NUMBER() over (order by o1.object_id) n from sys.all_objects o1) num
```

Very fast

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get started using a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT CAST('2018-01-01 10:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS StartDate
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(MI, 15, StartDate)
FROM cte
WHERE StartDate < '2018-01-01 13:00:00.000'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Note: the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)` sets the maximum recursion. By omitting this line the default is 100.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME = '10:00'
DECLARE @EndTime TIME = '13:00'

;WITH Recu AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedTime = @StartTime

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GeneratedTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, R.GeneratedTime)
    FROM
        Recu AS R
    WHERE
        R.GeneratedTime < @EndTime
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Recu AS R
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 32000)

/*
Result:
    GeneratedTime
    10:00:00.0000000
    10:15:00.0000000
    10:30:00.0000000
    10:45:00.0000000
    11:00:00.0000000
    11:15:00.0000000
    11:30:00.0000000
    11:45:00.0000000
    12:00:00.0000000
    12:15:00.0000000
    12:30:00.0000000
    12:45:00.0000000
    13:00:00.0000000
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Tally table:

```
DECLARE @Start_Time time = '10:00:00', @End_time time = '13:00:00';

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, Number, @Start_Time)
FROM Tally
WHERE Number % 15 = 0
AND DATEADD(MINUTE, Number, '1900-01-01' + CAST(@Start_Time As DateTime)) < 
                            '1900-01-01' + CAST(@End_time As DateTime)
```

If you don't already have a Tally table, you can use this script to create it:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,0,1) AS Number -- Note: Starts at 0!
    INTO Tally
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
ALTER TABLE Tally ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

If you don't know what a tally table is, and why you should have one, read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)